# Query Update where higher data in same table Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle11g

i have table data like this, namely DATA table:

```
DATA
-------------------------------
NIK         TIME        ACTION
-------------------------------
1500671     07:30:00    0
1500671     15:37:00    0
1600005     07:25:00    0
1600005     16:29:00    0
1600006     07:16:00    0
1600006     17:15:00    0
```

in that table i wanna update data set ACTION=1 where time is higher in same NIK. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please describe the problem appropriately when asking for assistance in technical forums. eg: ddl, test data etc. Anyway, I hope the below helps you.

```
UPDATE DATA
SET ACTION = 1
WHERE TIME IN (
SELECT MAX(TIME) FROM DATA GROUP BY NIK)
```